# Split a string between words and insert newlines

Tags: c, arrays, string, split

i have a string that is made out of a few sentences.
for example:

```
 hello world bye bye
```

now, i need to make this sentence into a coulmn of words:

```
hello
world
bye
bye
```

i have this idea going on, but i dont know how to write it correctly, so i was hopiny ypu guys could help me out.
this is what i have so far:

```
int len=0, k=0, stopatspace=0;
char temptext[100][15]={0};
char line[300]={0};

   len=strlen(line);
   printf("len is: %d", len);
   for(k=0; k<len; k++)
   {
       if (k == ' ')
       {
           // i dont know what to write here in order to make it a cloumn 
       }
   }
```

basiclly, my idea is to run on all the length of my line and when i reach a space i want it to enter (to go one line down so that it will look like a coulmn)

Comment: When you say "make it a column of words", do you want to _store_ the data or do you just want to _print_ the text as columns? (I know you have this variable `temptext`, but you don't seem use it, and your question isn't very clear.)

Comment: lili, If you have any requirements such as "I cannot use pointers",please mention it in your question.

Comment: In simple words, implementing your idea in C without any pointer is impossible unless the number of tokens and their lengths are explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `line` is the `char` array that contains `hello world bye bye` and `text` is declared as

```
char text[100][15]; //I used 100 and 15 because your example contains it
```

and you want each word to be copied into each row of `text`. Then,use [`strtok()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) function with `" "`(space) as delimeter and place this in a loop that terminates when `strtok()` returns `NULL` to get each word. Copy each word to each row of `text` using [`strcpy()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) in the loop.

The code for this will look like this:

```
char text[100][15];
char line[]="hello world bye bye";
int i=0;

char *token=strtok(line," ");

while(token!=NULL)
{
  strcpy(text[i],token);
  i++;
  token=strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

Now, to print it,you can use

```
for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
  printf("text[%d]=%s",j,text[j]);
```

---

Another method would be to manually copy each character until a space is seen.

```
int len=strlen(line);
int i=0;
int k=0;

for(int j=0;j<len+1;j++)
{
  if(line[j]==' ')
  {
    text[i][k]='\0';
    i++;
    k=0;
  }
  else
  {
    text[i][k]=line[j];
    k++;
  }
}
```

Note that the above code does not prevent [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). You can print each word using

```
for(int j=0;j<i+1;j++)
  printf("text[%d]=%s",j,text[j]);
```

Comment: I showed the same thing and the OP says pointers should not be used :(

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char string[100];
        fgets(string, 100, stdin);
        string[strlen(string)-1] = 0;

        // create an array of pointers
        char **string_array = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));

        int i = 0, array_size;

        // tokenize input
        char *token = strtok(string, " ");
        while(token!=NULL) {
                // dynamically increase the array during run time
                string_array = (char**)realloc(string_array, (i+1)*sizeof(char**));
                // create the string as you would do when there is only one string
                string_array[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
                strcpy(string_array[i], token);
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                i++;
        }
        array_size = i;

        for(i=0; i<array_size; i++) {
               printf("%s\n", string_array[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Basically you create an array of pointers and you allot memory for the strings one by one as you would do when there is only one string.
(if number of token is unknown, use realloc to increase the size of pointer to pointers.)

Comment: @Gopi , OP never mentioned that in his post so most people would not notice it as OP told it only as a comment under my answer(and your deleted answer).

Comment: @Gopi , As a matter of fact, OP mentioned in his question: "my idea is to run on all the length of my line and when i reach a space i want it to enter" and the question is titled "converting a string to a 2d array". Yet there is not way of doing that without playing with pointers because the number of tokens and their lengths are unknown prior to user input. Thus the array must be created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char line[300] = "hello world bye bye\n";
    char temptext[100][15]={0};
    int i=0, j, k=0;

    while(line[k]){
        if(isspace(line[k])){
            ++k;//skip space to word
            continue;
        }
        for(j=0; j < 15-1 && line[k] && !isspace(line[k]); ++k, ++j)
            temptext[i][j] = line[k];
        if(j && ++i == 100)
            break;
    }
    for(j=0; j<i; ++j)
        puts(temptext[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NEWLINE printf("\n")
int main(void)
{
        char string[]="hello world bye bye";
        int index=0;
        while(string[index])
        {
                if(string[index]==32)
                {
                        NEWLINE;
                        index++;
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("%c",string[index]);
                        index++;
                }
        }
        NEWLINE;
}

// Whenever i encountered with a space, i am printing a new line on the screen. Here 32       is the ASCII value for space
```

Comment: I like this simple solution, because that might well be what the OP wants. But why the ugly macro `NEWLINE` which doesn't buy you anything? And why the hard-codes number 32 instead of `' '`? Why don't you move the increment out of the conditional blocks, so that it occurs only once? And please return a value from `main`. (Not my downvote, by the way.)